# Navigation Drawer and action bar in all activity?

Tags: android, navigation

I have implemented actionbar and navigation drawer on all activity by extending base activity but when i use setcontent view  in child activity navigation drawer doesn't works at how to solve this! Here is my code:

MainActivity which contains navigation drawer:

```
package first.service.precision.servicefirst;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class Main2Activity extends Activity {
    public static ContactView contactView;
    NewContacts newContacts;

    public static LeadRequirementsView _LeadRequirements;
//public ContactView contactView;

   protected DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

public static  String mysting;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    Button butonlead;
    // ActionBarDrawerToggle indicates the presence of Navigation Drawer in the action bar
    protected ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // Title of the action bar
    private String mTitle = "";


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        final ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
        ab.show();
        // Getting reference to the DrawerLayout
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ab.setTitle(mTitle);

        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);

        // Getting reference to the ActionBarDrawerToggle
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,

                R.string.open_drawer,
                R.string.close_drawer) {

            /** Called when drawer is closed */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {

                invalidateOptionsMenu();

            }

            /** Called when a drawer is opened */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }


        };

        // Setting DrawerToggle on DrawerLayout
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        // Creating an ArrayAdapter to add items to the listview mDrawerList
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplication(),
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, R.id.title, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.option));

        // Setting the adapter on mDrawerList
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Enabling Home button
        ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#53A93F")));
        // Enabling Up navigation
        ab.setIcon(R.drawable.sfwhite);
        ab.show();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Setting item click listener for the listview mDrawerList
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                // Getting an array of options
                String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.option);

                // Currently selected option
                mTitle = menuItems[position];

            //    Fragment fragment = null;
              //  String tag = "";
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent lead=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LeadActivity.class);
                        startActivity(lead);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Intent opportunities=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),OpportunitiesActivity .class);
                        startActivity(opportunities);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                      Intent Accounts=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AccountsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(Accounts);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Intent Contacts=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Contacts.class);
                        startActivity(Contacts);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Intent Competitors=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Competitors.class);
                        startActivity(Competitors);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Intent Acivity=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activitites.class);
                        startActivity(Acivity);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        Intent Reports=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ReportActivity.class);
                        startActivity(Reports);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    //    int back=getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        }
else {
            super.onBackPressed();

        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu()
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);


        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

 /*   @Override
    public void data(String str, String sl) {
Accounts accounts=(Accounts)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("accounts");
        accounts.datarecieve(str,sl);

    }*/

    /*@Override
    public void dataTo(ContactView contactView) {
        Contactss contactss=(Contactss)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("contact");
      contactss.dataTo(contactView);
    }*/



   /* @Override
    public void DataTransfer(String e) {


    }*/
//
    // @Override
    //  public void DataTransfer(ArrayList<String> e) {
    //     Add obj=(Add)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_1);
    //   obj.GetlistContact(e);
    // }
}
  /*  @Override
    public void selectedvalue(String s) {
            Add add=new Add();
            FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame,add);
            ft.commit();}
    }
*/
```

Here is chlid activity which extends base activity

```
package first.service.precision.servicefirst;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LeadActivity extends Main2Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
super.  setContentView(R.layout.activity_lead);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_lead, null, false);
        mDrawerLayout.addView(contentView, 0);
        ArrayList<NewsItem> listContact = GetlistContact();
        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, listContact));

    }
    private ArrayList<NewsItem> GetlistContact(){
        ArrayList<NewsItem> contactlist = new ArrayList<NewsItem>();

        NewsItem contact = new NewsItem();
        for(int i=1;i<=30;i++) {
            contact = new NewsItem();
            contact.setHeadline("Yoge " +i);
            contact.setReporterName("Yogeshwaran" + i);
            contact.setLeadsource("Yogan" + i);
            contact.setLeadStatus("open" + i);
            contact.setLeadType("Business"+i);
            contactlist.add(contact);

        }

        return contactlist;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

am trying to populate listview in child activity i can get the listview but navigation drawer is missing how to solve this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this purpose you can use to [View Stub](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html) in your XML file, which will common for all Java files. Means you should make a separate XML (i.e write common code for all xml file into this one) and access this XML file in different-different java files (activity files). 
You can better understand from below line of code.
Add following in your master/common XML file which contain to navigation drawer and action bar with **View Stub**.

```
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/Home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home"
        tools:context="com.example.bhuvneshgautam.cityretails.HomeActivity">

        <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/layout_stub"
            android:inflatedId="@+id/message_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.75" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

now add below line of code in your each java file(activity java file)
in on Create

```
    ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.layout_stub);
    stub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.home_content);
    View inflated = stub.inflate();

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
```

Now use to "R.layout.home_content" for passing to XML file name which contain to code which you want to different in different pages.Below is one file code of my project which contain to separate code which i want to different in that file.
In home_content.xml

```
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/Hpersonalcare"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/personalcare"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to use View Stub

```
           <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/layout_stub"
            android:inflatedId="@+id/message_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.75" />
```

in your MainActivity....

Main2Activity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

.........................
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.....................

    ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.lay_stub);
    stub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.home_content);
    View inflated = stub.inflate();

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tlbar);
    setSupportActionBar(tlbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
```

Answer (score 1):

dont use `setContentView(...)` again, it overwrites this call in `Main2Activity` removing drawer. let your "main" `Activity` be abstract and create `protected abstract int getCustomContentView(...)` which will be available in all extending `Activities`, return id which you have currently passing inside `setContentView` and inflate it in parent and add to container in Drawer. it might be done inside `OnCreate` so after super you can call directly after `findViewById`in childs

```
public abstract class Main2Activity extends Activity {

    protected abstract int getCustomContentViewResId();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_container);
        int layoutResourceId = getCustomContentView();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View innerView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId , container, true);

        //rest of code

    }

}
```

Lead:

```
public class LeadActivity extends Main2Activity {

protected int getCustomContentViewResId(){
    return R.layout.activity_lead;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_lead);
    // this goes to getCustomContentViewResId

    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    // inflating already done in super.onCreate by extended Main2Activity so you may call findViewById directly without setContentView
    }

//rest of code
}
```

Comment: can you share some snippet as am new for android